# Add offset to UTC date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, timezone-offset

I have UTC date and want to add offset say 330 minutes to it.

```
var now = new Date(); 
var now_utc = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(),  now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
var offset = 330;

var new_date = ????
```

Comment: new_date = new Date((now_utc * 1) + offset)

Comment: No its giving me the same UTC date...

Comment: I disagree, it's the same date plus 330 - for example, I get now_utc = `2016-08-02T20:36:35.000Z` and new_date=`2016-08-02T20:36:35.330Z` ... see how they differ by exactly 330

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried it in console... Here is what I got... `new Date(now_utc)
Wed Aug 03 2016 06:40:14 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
new Date((now_utc * 1) + 330)
Wed Aug 03 2016 06:40:14 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

Comment: you're not displaying milliseconds, firefox displays milliseconds like I showed above - and 330 is less than 1 second, hence why whatever browser your using it looks the same

Comment: @JaromandaX See the updated comment..

Comment: see the updated response

Comment: @JaromandaX Bro.. It should be `new_date = new Date((now_utc * 1) + (330*60*1000))`

Comment: You wanted to add 330. Only now do you imply you meant minutes. I don't read minds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new_date = new Date((now_utc * 1) + (330*60*1000))
```